# How to duplicate all occurrences of a specific Character in a C-String

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function which duplicates all occurrences of a character in a C-String.

So for example if I call the function foo:

```
char input_str[] = "Alabama"
char c = 'a'

foo(input_str, c);
```

The output should be : `AAlaabaamaa`

This is my function so far:

```
void foo(char *str ,char ch){

    unsigned long len = strlen(str);
    char str_old[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        str_old[i] = str[i];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        int l = k + 1;
        if (str_old[k] == ch ) {
            str[l] = str_old[k];
             str[l+1] = str_old[k];
        }
        else{
            str[l] = str_old[k];
        }
    }


}
```

And I get the output:

`AAlabamaa` with a `SIGABRT` error.

Where am I going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely, you're trying to modify a string literal — that isn't allowed.  You need to allocate enough space for the extra characters (and remember the trailing null byte) too.  You might be simply running off the end of the array because your `foo()` does not null terminate the string it copies.

Comment: For analysis of problems as mentioned by Jonathan you have to provide a [mre].

Comment: `GDB` can help here.

Comment: @Achal Since I agree with Jonathans comment I don't think that GDB will make OP aware of the problem.

Comment: `char input_str[] = "Alabama";` makes an array with exactly enough space for “Alabama”. You can’t write a bigger string into it without making a bigger array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler He has `char input_str[] = "Alabama"` that's not a string literal.

Comment: @Barmar: OK — then the second and third sentences of my comment apply — as does the comment by Ry-.

Comment: OP, first find the number of `ch` and declare `str_old` equal to size of `str` plus `count+1`. For e.g `char str_old[len + count + 1] = {};` Here `count` is the number of `ch` and `+1` is for terminating `\0` char

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

First, your input array isn't big enough to hold the result. When you declare an array with `[]` size, it allocates just enough space for the initial value (including the null terminator when you initialize with a string literal). You need to give an explicit length, and make sure it allows room for all the duplicates. Doubling the size of the literal will do that.

```
char input_str[sizeof "Alabama" * 2] = "Alabama";
```

Second, your algorithm is wrong. After you duplicate characters, the index to store the results is no longer `k+1`. You should increment `l` every time you store a character in the output array.

```
    for (int k = 0, l = 0; k < len; k++, l++) {
        str[l] = str_old[k];
        if (str_old[k] == ch) {
            str[++l] = str_old[k];
        }
    }
```